# How can I add markup above the table in a custom module?

Tags: theming

I am working on a Drupal 8 custom module which renders pages as shown in the following image.

[image: screenshot]

So far, I am able to build the table and my code is the following.

```
  public function dexp_layerslider_list() {
    $header = [
        'ID',
        'Name',
        'Action',
    ] ;
    $results = db_select('{dexp_layerslider}', 'd')->fields('d', [
        'id',
        'name',
    ])->execute();
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $url = Url::fromUserInput("/admin/dexp_layerslider/". $row->id . "/edit");
        $row->name = (Link::fromTextAndUrl($row->name, $url));
        $editslides = Url::fromUserInput('/admin/dexp_layerslider/'.$row->id.'/editslides');
        $editslides_link = (Link::fromTextAndUrl('Edit slides', $editslides))->toString();
        $exportslides = Url::fromUserInput('/admin/dexp_layerslider/'. $row->id . '/export');
        $exportslides_link =  (Link::fromTextAndUrl('Export slides', $exportslides))->toString();
        $deleteslides = Url::fromUserInput('/admin/dexp_layerslider/'. $row->id . '/delete');
        $deleteslides_link =  (Link::fromTextAndUrl('Delete', $deleteslides))->toString();
     $tmp =  [
            '#type' => 'inline_template',
             '#template' => '{{ link1 |raw }}, {{ link2 | raw }}, {{ link3 | raw}}',
                '#context' => [
                         'link1' => $editslides_link->getGeneratedLink(),
                         'link2' => $exportslides_link->getGeneratedLink(),
                            'link3' => $deleteslides_link->getGeneratedLink(),
                            ]
                    ];
        // Row with attributes on the row and some of its cells.
     $rows[] = array(
            'data' => array($row->id,$row->name,$tmp )
                );
        }
     $table = array(
        '#type' => 'table',
        '#header' => $header,
        '#rows' => $rows,
        '#sticky' => FALSE,
        '#empty' => t('No slider created yet.'),
         );
        for($i= 0; $i
            $table['#rows'][$i]['data'][2] = $tmp;
        }
    return $table;
 }
```

How do I add a "Add slide" and "Export slide" links?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple solutions to achieve what you want

1. Using #prefix

   ```
    $table = array(
     '#prefix'=> '<div><a>my link</a></div>',
     '#type' => 'table',
     '#header' => $header,
     '#rows' => $rows,
     '#sticky' => FALSE,
     '#empty' => t('No slider created yet.'),
    );
   for($i= 0; $i
       $table['#rows'][$i]['data'][2] = $tmp;
   }
   ```
2. A better way to do this is

   ```
    $table = array(
     'links' => [
        '#type'=> 'container'
        'link_one'=> [
           '#type' => 'link',
           '#title' => $this->t('Add slide'),
           '#url' => Url::fromRoute('my_route'),
         ],
      ],
     '#type' => 'table',
     '#header' => $header,
     '#rows' => $rows,
     '#sticky' => FALSE,
     '#empty' => t('No slider created yet.'),
    );
   for($i= 0; $i
       $table['#rows'][$i]['data'][2] = $tmp;
   }
   ```
3. Add module definied actions: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/menu-api/providing-module-defined-actions

Comment: Third option was best , second option appends the link at bottom of table.

Comment: you can add a #weight to put it above the table